# Use results from one useQuery hook within another useQuery hook to cache raw AND transformed data

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have been using [tanstack react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest) to fetch a list of objects from an API (let's call this **Query_A**). Now I want to be able to fetch and cache an *aggregated* version of this same data set (let's call this **Query_B**). Is there some nifty built-in way of re-using the data that was fetched and cached by **Query_A** from within **Query_B**? If not, is it just considered an anti-pattern and is that why I haven't seen this sort of implementation before? Should I just de-couple the two queries and run the same query twice in order to cache two different results?

I'm wondering if I can / should do something like this:

```js
export const Query_A = (
  parameters: string[]
) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['Query_A', parameters],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const rawResult = await apiClient.request('/my/endpoint/', parameters);
      return rawResult;
    }
  })
};


export const Query_B = (
  parameters: string[]
) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['Query_B', parameters],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const {
        data,
        error,
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
        isError,
        isSuccess,
      } = Query_A(parameters);

      const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        while ((isLoading || isFetching) && data === undefined) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.debug('waiting for data to be returned');
          }, 100);
        }
        
        if (isSuccess) {
          resolve(data);
        }
        if (isError) {
          reject(new Error('Something went wrong!', error));
        }
      });

      await myPromise.then((data) => {
        return data;
      }).catch((error) => {
        return error;
      });
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: `while ((isLoading || isFetching) && data === undefined)` will never work. That's an infinite loop, as the `const`s that the condition is based on will never change. And that's not how `setTimeout` works either.

Comment: `Query_A` is a hook (it should be named `useQueryA` or just `useA`), it must not be called from the `async` queryFn.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `useMemo`?

Comment: @Bergi The original idea was to cache the transformed data that could be used by  other components, rather than caching within individual components. At this point, I'm thinking that this isn't a good idea to nest `useQuery` instances because that would break the [rules of hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#breaking-rules-of-hooks) and it also tightly couples the logic between the two hooks. I think the answer here is to accept the overhead in making separate API calls in separate `useQuery` instances , and using `useMemo` per component.

Comment: Ah I see. Not sure if ["data selectors"](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#new-features) would help with this. They don't seem to be documented particularly well though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a second `useQuery` just to transform some data, there's simpler solutions

**Option 1:**

How about just transforming the data outside of the hook:

```
const { data } = useQueryA()
const aggregatedData = aggregateData(data);
```

And if `aggregateData()` is an expensive, wrap it in a useMemo:

```
const { data } = useQueryA()
const aggregatedData = React.useMemo(() => aggregateData(data), [data]);
```

**Option 2:**

And if you want it to be reusable, wrap in a simple custom hook:

```
const useQueryAWithAggregate = () => {
  const query = useQueryA();
  return {
    ...query,
    aggregatedData: React.useMemo(
      () => query?.data && aggregateData(query.data),
      [query.data]
    );
  }
}
```

**Option 3:**

Use [select with a partial subscription](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations#3-using-the-select-option):

```
export const useQueryA = (
  parameters: string[]
  select?: (data: Result) => Result
) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['Query_A', parameters],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const rawResult = await apiClient.request('/my/endpoint/', parameters);
      return rawResult;
    },
    select
  })
};

const useQueryAAggregate = (parameters) => {
  return useQueryA(parameters, (result) => { 
    // transform data here and return it
  })
}
```

I have not tested this approach to see if it calculates aggregate on each component.

*EDIT*

**Option 4:**

if you really want to avoid memoisation in each component you could either use context or transform in the query function:

```
export const useQueryA = (
  parameters: string[]
) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['Query_A', parameters],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const rawResult = await apiClient.request('/my/endpoint/', parameters);
      return {
        rawResult,
        aggregatedData: aggregateData(rawResult)
      };
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: A custom hook makes the logic reusable, but keeps the state (and the memoisation) in each separate component. OP was hoping "*to cache the transformed data that could be used by other components, rather than caching within individual components*" - do you know whether that is (not) possible with react-query?